# App Roles Assignment by Microsoft Graph API

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api

Currently I can assign roles to users using the azure portal. How can I do by just hitting an api so that I don't have to go the portal for every user ?

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using the Activate directoryRole API:
[image]

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryRoles
Content-type: application/json

{
  "roleTemplateId": "fe930be7-5e62-47db-91af-98c3a49a38b1"
}
```

For checking the Directory role object id please refer:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/directoryrole-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http.

Hope this helps.